# Forking server for handling many clients c++

Tags: c++, sockets, fork, multiple-instances

I'm kinda new to network programming and I'm trying to make a socket server that could handle multiple clients. The server will be a connection between players and a game engine for a text-based adventure, written in c++.

I got the code working for single clients, and for sending data between client and server. The next step in the implementation is to make it able to handle multiple clients. For what I understand fork is way to do this. I've got this code this far, but I can't for my life get it to work.

```
while (1) {
    cout << "Server waiting." << endl;
    n = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if ((clientSocket = accept(servSocket, (struct sockaddr*) (&client), (socklen_t*) (&n))) < 0) {
        cerr << "Error: " << errno << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
    if(fork() == 0){
        cout << "Child process created. Handling connection with << " << inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, buff, sizeof(buff)) << endl;
        close(servSocket);
    }
    string sendmsg;
    string recvmsg;
    int bytesRecieved = 0;
    char package[1024];
    string playerMessage;
    while(1){
        bytesRecieved = recv(clientSocket, package, 1024, 0);
        for (int offset = 0; offset < bytesRecieved/sizeof(char); ++offset) {
           playerMessage += package[offset];
        }
        cout << playerMessage;
        cin >> sendmsg;
        sendmsg += "\n";
        send(clientSocket, sendmsg.c_str(), sendmsg.size(), 0);
    }
}
close(clientSocket);
close(servSocket);
return 0;
```

I understand that the bind() and everything before that should happend before the main-loop with fork() in it, so I didn't bother to include that.

Thanks on beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

Creating process per connection is a wrong way in most cases. What if you have 20'000 players? Context switching for 20'000 processes makes too much overhead slowing down the server.

Consider using async programming. `boost::asio` is one of the best choices then.